# Странный перевод ошибок при вводе слишком длинной ссылки на Github/Twitter

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

> Не удалось распознать введённую ссылку или имя пользователяGitHub как
>   корректную ссылку или имя пользователя GitHub.

Хотя в transifex: "**Не удалось распознать введённую ссылку или имя пользователя как корректную ссылку на GitHub или имя пользователя.**":

https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/137316522

и

> Не удалось распознать введённую ссылку или имя пользователяTwitter как
>   корректную ссылку или имя пользователя Twitter.

Хотя в transifex: "**Не удалось распознать введённую ссылку или имя пользователя как корректную ссылку на Твиттер или имя пользователя.**":

https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/137316601

Comment: А какая связь перевода и длинной ссылки? А, два раза название ресурса в строке. Да, странно, если так.

Comment: @alexolut ага, странно)

Comment: Надо на MSE переносить, имхо. Сделать акцент на том, что пролезает латиница "Twitter" в строку вместо русского "Твиттер". Какой-то хардкод имеет место быть.

Comment: @alexolut ок. Чуть позже задам.

Comment: Задайте им там!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После последнего обновления переводов исправилось.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вижу проблему.

1. Есть такие строки для Гитхаба и Твиттера:

   https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/137316522

   https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/137316601

   И именно эти строки используются на en SO.
2. Но у нас они не используются. А используется вот эта строка:

   https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/139847494

   Там в переводе пробел пропущен.

   Это баг и стоит про это на MSE писать?

Ошибка на en SO:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка у нас:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все 3 строки в трансе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос на MSE: [Generic string is used on localized sites instead of unique for Web presence fields errors on profile settings page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314625/260198)

Comment: `И именно эти строки используются на en SO` - откуда инсайд?

Comment: @vp_arth сам проверил)

Comment: Ну таки строки совпадают, не? Используется последняя

Comment: @vp_arth у нас последняя с подстановкой. У них под каждую сеть своя строка.

Comment: Каким образом можно выяснить разницу? Везде используется 139847494 с подстановкой.

Comment: @vp_arth я картинки прикрепил.

Comment: @vp_arth говорит о том, что после подстановки английские строки не различимы. Поэтому нельзя с достаточной уверенностью сказать какие там строки используются.